# How to show processes that use more than 30% CPU?

Tags: linux, process

I need to display processes that use more than 30% CPU via command top. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Filtering within `top` with <kbd>o</kbd> (small 'o'). After pressing you see a line for your command (something like `add filter #1 (ignoring case) as: [!]FLD?VAL`. Just write down, what you want to see: `%CPU>30.0`. And hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Tadah!

More details can be found with `FILTERING in a Window` section of `man top`

---

Older part of the post:

```
ps -eo %cpu,args | awk '$1 >= 30 {print}'
```

`ps` command list all processes with their cpu usage (in percent) and args (see `man ps` for more options under `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS` section) and `awk` than print only these with first column `>=` 30.

Comment: d'oh, I missed 'via top command' suffix..

Comment: ... so I added the right answer :)

Comment: Note that the percent output here is a percent of **1** CPU. So, if the command shows a process is taking 52% of the CPU, that's 52% of **1** CPU. Assuming you have 8 CPUs, that means the overall percent of your processing power taken by that process is equal to `52/(8*100) = 0.065 = 6.5%`.

Comment: To see instantaneous overall CPU usage, see my answer here: [Stack Overflow: How to get overall CPU usage (e.g. 57%) on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux/70760502#70760502)

Answer (score 0):

For Rhel, run `top` command. Then press shift + f and then press k followed by Enter. This will sort the output by CPU usage.

Comment: Why only RHEL? This applies to every GNU/Linux system.

Comment: Because shift + f doesn't work in SunOS.

Comment: I said it applies to every GNU/Linux system. Linux != SunOS. There are indeed differences between *nixes but top on every Linux distro is the same.

Comment: Apology,  I missed that part.