# Command-line command to see CPU usage of Chrome tab, as shown in Chrome Task Manager

Tags: chrome, cpu-usage

Chrome Task Manager can be opened by clicking the 3 dots in top-right of Chrome --> More Tools --> Task manager. It looks like this:

[image]

[`ps -eo %cpu,args | awk '$1 >= 30 {print}'`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295599/how-to-show-processes-that-use-more-than-30-cpu/295608#295608) tells me this Chrome process is using > 30% of one CPU:

> 30.3 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --enable-crashpad --crashpad-handler-pid=376 --enable-crash-reporter=268aff53-36a9-4582-a3c8-e90265a8e7eb, --display-capture-permissions-policy-allowed --origin-trial-disabled-features=CaptureHandle --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --enable-logging --v=1 --field-trial-handle=16790865900654175629,8097267719301694013,131072 --lang=en-US --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=75 --launch-time-ticks=99466415943 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100

But, I cannot tell which tab that is. Any way to find out via the command-line? Any way to script it or write a program for this?

The Python `psutil` module (this code is [from my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70760502/4561887)), tells me overall and individual CPU usage information:

```bsh
printf "%b" "import psutil\n\
cpu_percent_cores = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2, percpu=True)\n\
avg = sum(cpu_percent_cores)/len(cpu_percent_cores)\n\
cpu_percent_total_str = ('%.2f' % avg) + '%'\n\
cpu_percent_cores_str = [('%.2f' % x) + '%' for x in cpu_percent_cores]\n\
print('Total: {}'.format(cpu_percent_total_str))\n\
print('Individual CPUs: {}'.format('  '.join(cpu_percent_cores_str)))\n\
" | python3
```

Can psutil, or another program, tell me more info about Chrome tab usage?

See also:

1. [my question] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70763756/how-to-read-data-from-the-chrome-task-manager-and-log-cpu-usage-of-individual-ta